# docker ee windows server 2016 cannot create network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-server-2016, docker-network

I'm new in Docker, I'm trying to create a network using the driver bridge

```
docker network create -d bridge DockerNet
```

but I keep getting the error: Error response from daemon: plugin not found.

I also tried to use

```
docker network create -d l2bridge DockerNet
```

as the plugin shown in docker info is named `l2bridge`.

docker info:

```
 Containers: 4
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-14
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd json-file logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.2248.amd64fre.rs1_release.180427-1804)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2016 Standard
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.89GiB
 Name: DesDocker
 ID: BVHA:4FUO:OE3N:AM4R:XHAC:S4SV:VIRN:W73F:IVTF:RWFG:FVGQ:LMWE
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode (client): false
 Debug Mode (server): false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

But it returned another error: `Error response from daemon: HNS failed with error : Element not found.`

I have also tried to create it using `docker-compose` but it returns the same error for both bridge and `l2bridge`.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  Container1:
    image: microsoft/windowsservercore
    networks:
      - DockerNet

networks:
  DockerNet:
    driver: default
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.48.0/20
```

The docker version I'm using is `17.06.2-ee-14` and the output of docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-14
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.7
 Git commit:   6345dd7
 Built:        Thu Jun 21 18:16:45 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-14
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   6345dd7
  Built:        Thu Jun 21 18:28:51 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

The thing is if I create using NAT as the driver:

```
docker network create -d nat DockerNet
```

It creates without error and I can see it in `docker network ls`.

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong? or what should I do to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same exact issue, it seems to be rampant. Can't believe devs have not fixed this by now boggles the mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the available networks: docker network ls you will see an entry for nat. Use that as your network.